# How to embed google analytics into google site?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the javascript code (the analytics snippet) and I have the UA code and site stats all set up I want to be able to post the analytics statistics themselves into the website itself. Here is the analytics snippet I want to embed into the google site:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

When I post this code with my UA code into the google site insert button for google site nothing appears just a blank box. How can I get this code to post the google analytics onto the google site itself?

Thank you

Comment: Could you perhaps post some screenshots so we might better understand your problem?

Answer (score 0):

For google sites, use this documentation to add Google Analytics: https://support.google.com/sites/answer/97459?hl=en